# What's the difference between build and release in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, apk

Why the size of `flutter build apk --release` is larger than the size of `flutter run --release` which reduces the size by half. I need to get the leaner app size.

Comment: if you want smaller size of build apk, first run `flutter clean` then run `flutter build apk --release`

Comment: It didn't affect at all in my application. both ways 18.9mb but in `run --release` it it 7.4mb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should know that `flutter run --release` compiles only for a target ***ABI*** (because you run the generated APK directly to your device). while, `flutter build apk --release` results in a fat APK (Universal apk) that contains your code compiled for all the target ***ABIs***, as a result, you could install this apk on any **device**.

Flutter app can be compiled for

- Armeabi-v7a (ARM 32-bit)
- Arm64-v8a (ARM 64-bit)
- x86-64 (x86 64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there are three main CPU architectures used in Android smartphones.

- **ARM**: ARMv7 or armeabi
- **ARM64**: AArch64 or arm64
- **x86**: x86 or x86abi

`flutter run --release` compiles only for your connected devices ABI (Application Binary Interface). So, you can install that apk only those devices that can matched with your device only.

`flutter build apk --release` compiles for all architecture, that's why you can install your apk on any device or any CPU architectures.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, a build refers to the process of taking your source code and turning it into a deployable app. There are two types of builds in Flutter: debug builds and release builds.
Debug builds are used for development and testing. They are built with debugging symbols enabled, which makes it easier to debug your code. Debug builds also include a debugger that allows you to pause the execution of your code and inspect variables and the call stack.
Release builds are used for deploying your app to app stores or distributing it to users. They are built with debugging symbols stripped, which makes the app smaller and faster. Release builds also have optimizations enabled, which makes the app even faster.
To create a release build in Flutter, you can use the flutter build command with the --release flag. For example:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

This will create a release build of your app in the build/app/outputs/apk directory.